# jquery : How to copy the text of a div/span to another div when you click on the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am only 5 days into Jquery, so the question may be noob.

```
<div class="Sub_Professions" id="Engineer_Sub_Professions" style="display: none;">
    <br /> <span id = "solTitle" class="profession_sub_1"> Civil Engineer </span>
    <br /> <span id = "solTitle" class="profession_sub_1"> Computer Engineer </span>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to toggle the style="display:none" on this div, when the user hovers over a certain text. Once this div is visible, I need a script where a person can click on Civil Engineer/Computer Engineer and the text gets copied to an another div `<div id="selected_professions">`

The below script is wrong and does not work.

```
$( "#solTitle" ).onclick(function() {
  var val = $( this ).text();
  $( "#selected_professions" ).append( "<b>val</b>" );
});
```

While I was posting this question, I observed that you can add Tags to this question, and when you click on the suggested tags, they appear in the Tags Input box and the selected tag gets dark(and non-usable) and appears in the input box. We can also enter the tags by typing and stackoverflow searches through its list of tags and adds the tag in there. We can also remove the tag by clicking on the X next to the tag. How to implement "the exact same thing" ?

Comment: Try this: `$( "#solTitle" ).onclick(function() {
  var val = $( this ).text();
  $( "#selected_professions" ).append( "<b>"+val+"</b>" );
});`

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are a few things that are making your code not work.

First, `onclick` is not a function. Use `.on('click' ...` instead.

Second, you need to use unique IDs for your HTML, so a better approach would be to give the two spans a common class of `solTitle`

Last, you can concatenate the `val` variable like this: `"<b>" + val + "</b>"`

Here's the full example

```js
$(".solTitle").on('click', function() {
  var val = $(this).text();
  $("#selected_professions").append("<b>" + val + "</b>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Sub_Professions" id="Engineer_Sub_Professions">
  <br /> <span class="solTitle" class="profession_sub_1"> Civil Engineer </span>
  <br /> <span class="solTitle" class="profession_sub_1"> Computer Engineer </span>
</div>

<div id="selected_professions">
</div>
```

The tag part of your question is sort of unclear. I'd recommend posting that as its own question entirely.

Comment: Alternatively, it could be `.on('click', function() { })`.

Comment: Yep, you're right, and I think that's the recommended syntax anyway. I'll update my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. I prefer you to use unique IDs for each element though.

```
$("#solTitle").on("click",function() {
  var val = $(this).text();
  $("#selected_professions").append("<b>" + val + "</b>");
});
```